# 'int' object has no attribute 'val'

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, nodes, attributeerror

I am having a problem with the following code. I'm trying to find the least common ancestor between two nodes on a binary search tree. The code I have is the following:

```
def Question4(T, r, p, q):
    s, b = sorted([p.val, q.val])
    while not s <= r.val <= b:
        r = r.left if s <= r.val else r.right
    return r
T = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
r = 3
p = 1
q = 4
Question4(T, r, p, q)
```

When I attempt to run this code my terminal output shows `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val'` at this line of code `s, b = sorted([p.val, q.val])` I'm not sure whats causing this, I looked up similar answers but could not find a solution. If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: Seems straightforward to me: `p` and `q` are integers. Integers don't have a `val` attribute. So you can't do `p.val` or `q.val`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `r` `p` `q` are all `int` type and they don't have any attribute `val` associated with them.

Now how can you find it. Use `dir` builtin function.

```
>>> r = 3
>>> dir(r)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']
```

You can see there is no `val` attribute associated with `int` object.

Now, how to fix the above problem.

```
def Question4(T, r, p, q):
    s, b = sorted([p, q])  // remove .val
    while not s <= r <= b: // remove .val
        r = r.left if s <= r else r.right // also int doesn't have .right or .left attribute, you need to define your own class to represent this custom data type
    return r
T = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
r = 3                // this is int object which don't have val attribute
p = 1
q = 4
Question4(T, r, p, q)
```

Comment: Both this answer and the one below were correct. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`p`, `q` and `r` are integers. Consequently they have no `val` attributes. Just remove the `.val` for these 3